# Can I pull user input from one package to another?

Tags: java

Okay so I am still fairly new to Java and there are a few things I can't quite understand. I do all my Java in Sublime 3 and I don't use an IDE so I have to manually create everything(probably why I can't get this to work). Here is what my code looks like:

```
package charactername;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner.*;
import java.lang.Object.*;

public class UserNameInput {

  public static void main(String[] args){

    String playerNameF;
    String playerNameL;
    String checking;
    boolean valid = true;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(valid){
    System.out.println("Enter the first name of your character here: ");

    playerNameF = in.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter the last name of your character here:");

    playerNameL = in.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Your character name will be: \n" + playerNameF + " " + playerNameL + "\nIs this correct? y/n");

    checking = in.nextLine();
    if(checking.equals("n") || checking.equals("no")){
      System.out.println("Please re-enter your information and try again.");
    }else if(checking.equals("y") || checking.equals("yes")){
      System.out.println("Good luck in game!");
      break;
    }else{
      System.out.println("Sorry, I didn't quite understand your input. Please re-enter your information and try again.");
      valid = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Can I use playerNameL; playerNameF in a completely separate package?

```
package gameintroduction.UserRegistration;

import charactername.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner.*;

  public class GettingStarted {
    public static void main(String[] args){

      UserNameInput cName = new UserNameInput();
      cName.playerNameF();
    }
  }
```

I am trying to pull it in here but it says the package doesn't exist. Does import have restrictions on it's scope? UserNameInput does compile and run, even if its ugly!

Comment: *I do all my Java in Sublime 3 and I don't use an IDE so I have to manually create everything(probably why I can't get this to work)* Agreed. Use an IDE. Stop trying to do all of your Java in Sublime 3. I too paid for a Sublime license. It's a very nice text editor. I do not use it for Java development. Why are you persisting in this?

Comment: My brother who started out as a Java programmer and now does Ruby advised me to use Text Editors when learning. IDE's like NetBeans teach you bad habits and do things for you that you might not understand. Right clicking and having all your packages made and organized for you, then another right click and having all your setters and getters made for you without any clue as to whats happening in the back end. Should I use an IDE? Its really rough to find answers to questions that can be answered with 2 right clicks in an IDE.

Comment: You should _definitely_ learn how to use an IDE, eg. Eclipse or IntelliJ because: (a) you will much more productive; (b) you can make use of a debugger; and (c) it will be expected knowledge if you end up working in the industry as a developer. I would argue that using an IDE to do boiler-plate work for you is a good habit, not a bad one. That said, you should understand what an IDE is doing for you in the back end, eg. when it creates setters and getters, but to avoid using an IDE because of these concerns is a very poor trade off in my view.

Comment: @KurtisHallquist Is there some reason you didn't ask your brother, who's advice this is, for help? When I first learned Java, there were no IDEs. My advice is the opposite of your brothers.

Comment: Asking my brother is not so easy. First, hes extremely condescending and arrogant and secondly, I know I can do this without having to be piggy backed by someone. I was just clueless on this particular issue because everyone uses IDEs and it is literally 2 right clicks and done for the problem im having. No one uses command prompt and text editors for java (if you know someone please send me a link!). @ElliottFrisch Did you make every package by hand as well? compile everything in cprompt? You would recommend an IDE?

Comment: @KurtisHallquist *Did you make every package by hand as well?* Yes. *compile everything in cprompt?* Yes. Although one generally would write an ant script (or at least a build script). Today this is usually done with maven (or sbt). *You would recommend an IDE?* **Yes**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring `playerNameF` inside `main()` which means this variable has scope inside of `main()` of `UserNameInput` class. In order to use it in other class decalre these variables as instance variables with public access specifier as shown below.Also instead of using main() inside `UserNameInput`  class use an instance method say `userInput()` and put all the logic of your main() inside it.

```
public class UserNameInput {
    public String playerNameF;
    public String playerNameL;
    public String checking;     

    public void userInput(){
        // your logic from main() comes here

    }
}
```

Now you can do `UserNameInput cName = new UserNameInput();cName.playerNameF;`
Now you can invoke it from other `main()` as shown below:

```
public class GettingStarted {
    public static void main(String[] args){

      UserNameInput cName = new UserNameInput();
      cName.userInput();
    }
  }
```

Also you can access the variables using `cName.playerNameF` or `cName.playerNameL`

Comment: Thanks for your help! It looks like I was close but not close enough :). I am still having the problem where package charactername doesn't exist when I try to import it, and since it can't find that; I also get the error cannot find symbol for UserNameInput. When I run my programs in command prompt, does it always have to be .java when I run the file name? For Example: I write a simple program, go into the folder in cprompt then javac filex.java then I should be able to java filex. But command prompt will say it cant find it. Then when I run that same program as java filex.java it works.